next_post_link and previous_post_link on custom post type without taxonomy?
I have a super basic custom post type projects that doesn't have any taxonomy.
I'm trying to show next/prev post links but they all show incorrect posts.
I've tried within and outside the loop, next_post_link() and get_adjacent_post() and nothing show correct posts, seems like the final argument ($category) breaking the fun functionality.
Is there something I can put there so it just show prev/next within all custom type posts?

The problem I think is that if you don't specify $taxonomy, it assumes category which is not present: get_adjacent_post( bool $in_same_term = false, int[]|string $excluded_terms = ”, bool $previous = true, string $taxonomy = ‘category’ )

Huh, yes sorry I see now. Yes, looks like you might have to clone get_adjacent_post and remove the taxonomy bit to work with your custom type. I guess they expect everyone to have a 'category' equivalent on their custom types.
